# Volatile: why prevent compiler reorder code

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

In java, with my knowledge, volatile variable make a thread reads/writes directly to main CPU (not in cache of each thread), so make its change visibles to other threads.

The thing  I  don't know is : So, why this work (of volatile) can prevent compiler/CPU reorder statement of code.

thanks :)

Comment: Note that this thing about volatile making reads avoid caches is a purely theoretical construct and does not really have all that much to do with what `volatile` actually does on real hardware. We just imagine that there's all kinds of things an implementation might do and that `volatile` guarantees that optimizations don't produce particular behaviors that we need to prohibit in particular cases.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is a very good example illustrating the issue the prohibition on reordering is aimed to address (taken from [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile)):

```
class VolatileExample {
    int x = 0;
    volatile boolean v = false;
    public void writer() {
        x = 42;
        v = true;
    }
    public void reader() {
        if (v == true) {
            //uses x - guaranteed to see 42.
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, `v` is volatile, but `x` is not. If writer and reader are executed concurrently and the reader sees `v` set to `true`, `x` is guaranteed to be `42`. Prior to Java-5, compiler was free to re-order the writes to `x` and `v`, so you could see `x` at zero *after* you've seen `v` set to `true`. This was confusing, and lead to subtle errors. Java-5 memory model addressed this issue by making volatile writes almost equivalent to synchronization.

Comment: I don't see how reader is guaranteed see x at 42. Sure the x=42 can happen before v=true, but reader() could still see a cached value of 0, no?

Comment: @Shawn Until Java-5 that was correct, but Java-5 memory model makes sure that all writes complete before the volatile write. See link for details.

Comment: I just ran my code based on this answer and noticed the following fact. if v is declared true, the compiler can delete the line `v = true;`, and the value of x will remain 0 in `reader()`. See [my gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e5fc26aa20a85757368)

Comment: but if x is set after v is set in writer(), then reader() either see x to be 42 or 0

Answer (score 5):

That's just how the language is defined.  Informally, marking a variable `volatile` in Java specifically tells the compiler that it should not reorder statements around it or optimize on its value, since that value might be modified concurrently in another thread.  The particular implementation of the JVM is then responsible for respecting this `volatile` modifier and taking appropriate precautions not to incorrectly optimize the program.

If you'd like more specific details about what language-level guarantees there are to ensure that `volatile` works correctly, you may want to look at [the Java Language Specification's description of the Java memory model](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4), which defines the abstract rules governing thread behavior.  It also describes how `volatile` interacts with these rules.

Hope this helps!