# Ordering atomic read with non-atomic read

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

Suppose I have an atomic variable `aa` and a non-atomic variable `na`. Is it possible to ensure that the atomic variable `aa` is read AFTER `na`?

In general, an acquire memory fence prevents loads from being reordered. Will it ensure ordering also in this case?
If not, is it possible to achieve this ordering without making `na` atomic and without using a strong memory fence (i.e., sequential consistency) for the reader, which is significantly more expansive?

```
int na{0}; 
atomic<int> aa{0}; 

void thread1(){
    int l1 = na; 
    std::signal_memory_fence(std::memory_order_acquire); 
    int l2 = aa;
    assert( l2==0 || l1==1 ); //does this hold?
    //if reading from aa observed the latest value 1, reading from na cannot have an earlier value 
}
void thread2(){
    aa.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst); 
    na = 1; 
}
```

Thanks

P.S. The main difference from the following question [Re-ordering Atomic Reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554587/re-ordering-atomic-reads) is that the first variable is assumed to be non atomic.

Comment: If the first variable is assumed to be non-atomic, the code becomes illegal since you need protection for this variable

Comment: This works on x86 and I assume on any architecture that does not reorder reads. The question is if this is guaranteed by c++11

Comment: `na` must be atomic, or you have undefined behavior. On `X86`, you'll probably get away with declaring it `volatile`. Since `X86` preserves the order of 2 independent stores, thread1 will observe them in the order as committed by thread2 (the compiler may still reorder your stores, even with the seq/cst store on `aa`, although unlikely). But even with no reordering at all, the assert can fire on `l2==1` and `l1==0` since that is a legitimate outcome.